# Calling different factory methods based on variable string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have factory methods like this

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Users', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/MY/system/users');
    })
    .factory('Groups', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/MY/system/groups');
    });
```

I can call Users.get() method and Groups.get() method. But how can I run these methods based on there string representation. Lets say I have generic method

```
function GenericCtrol($scope) {
    $scope.fmethod = 'Users'
    //how to run something like $scope.fmethod.get()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector):

```
function GenericCtrol($scope, $injector) {
    $scope.fmethod = 'Users';

    $injector.get($scope.fmethod).get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
function GenericCtrol($scope,Users,Groups) {
    $scope.Users=Users;
    $scope.Groups=Groups;
    $scope.fmethod = 'Users';
    $scope[$scope.fmethod].get();
}
```

as javascript object is just a key-value map.

Comment: thats bad... If I have some 10 factory objects and any one can be used with GenericCtrol do I need to pass all 10???

Comment: I don't think this is bad. You should make your dependency explicit. If there are 10 dependencies and you are magically switching them in your code, the code i believe become difficult to understand and maintain. You case maybe different. @Engineer has given a viable alternative.